# Swift - Calling .init on a closure type

Tags: swift

This is not something that has any actual applications, but it surprised me today and I would like to understand why it works.

So this is actually valid code:

```swift
var test: ((Bool) -> ())?

test = .init({a in print(a)})
```

This however is not

```swift
test = ((Bool) -> ()).init({a in print(a)})
```

Reason being "Type '(Bool) -> ()' has no member 'init'"

Why does example one work? What does the init call actually belong to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test` is a *optional* closure, and

```
test = .init({a in print(a)})
```

calls the `init` method of `Optional`, not of the closure type. It is an [“implicit member expression”](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html) because the type is inferred from the left-hand side. This also becomes apparent if you Option-click on the `.init` call in the Xcode source editor:

[image]

It is equivalent to both of

```
test = Optional.init({a in print(a)})
test = Optional({a in print(a)})
```

or just

```
test = {a in print(a)}
```

because the compiler automatically wraps an expression of type `T` into an `Optional<T>` if necessary.

Comment: That totally makes sense, it is sometimes easy to forget that optional is an actual type, with all the syntactic sugar... thanks